# jquery mobile error - cannot call methods on button prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'disabled'

Tags: jquery-mobile

According to the documentation (http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/api/events.html), the pageinit event should be called after all the widgets and plugins for a jQuery mobile page have been executed. So, I believe I should be able to interact with elements on that page with impunity in the event callback. However, I listen for the page to initialize and then try to interact with a button on the page, and I get the following error:

> cannot call methods on button prior to initialization; attempted to
>   call method 'disabled'

I've put together a codepen, to show you:

http://codepen.io/mattsnider/pen/mvcbD

What gives? Does the pageinit not work as documented or is this a bug?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with your `pageinit` event. The wrong lies in the `<a>` tag.

To remove the error you're getting, you'll have to make two changes to your code :

1. Its not `disabled`, its `disable`
2. before your call the `disable` method, you have to call `button()` method. Thus, you would've initialized the `button` element.

This is how the code will look like now :

```js
 $('#ageNext').button().button('disable');
```

But, if you do this, you'll get an error like this :

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'addClass' of undefined

The culprit lies in the code which invokes the `disable` method

```js
disable: function() {
  this.element.attr( "disabled", true );
  this.button.addClass( "ui-disabled" ).attr( "aria-disabled", true ); 
  //^^ Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'addClass' of undefined    
  return this._setOption( "disabled", true );
}
```

You see the `this.button` there? This will become `undefined` if the element is not a real button.

So that said, I've got the `disable`  to work only on `input[type=button]` and `<button/>` type of elements. For some reason, this doesn't work as expected on `<a/>` impersonating buttons. I've got this to work by manually adding `ui-disabled` class to the element, like this :

```js
$(document).on('pageinit', '#age', function (e) {
    $('#ageNext').addClass('ui-disabled');
});
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/hungerpain/gzAHT/

Comment: This still seems to apply in jQuery Mobile 1.4.5.

Answer (score 0):

This may also happen if you have unmatched HTML tags, especially troubling is `</div>` without a previously declared `<div>`.

First thing to check might be that your HTML is well formed.